# insert returns in grouped text for geom_text()

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to print a `geom_raster()` where the background color represents a count of the number of instances in the category, with a list of the names of the instances in the cell. Is there a way to insert returns in what is passed to `geom_text()`? Currently, the text is piled onto of itself in the center of each raster square, making it illegible. An reprex using mtcars below.

Thanks in advance!

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

tibble::as_tibble(mtcars, rownames = "make") %>% 
dplyr::filter(cyl == 4) %>% dplyr::group_by(vs, am) %>% 
dplyr::summarise(dark = n(), names = make) %>% 
ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = vs, y = am, alpha = dark, label = names)) + 
ggplot2::geom_raster() + 
ggplot2::geom_text()
```

Comment: FYI, the point of calling `library()` is that you don't have to write prefixes before functions.

Comment: @DanChaltiel But when you have other packages loaded, then there can be issues with calling the wrong function from another package. I always am explicit with the name of the package. It's easier to know where a function comes from and if someone reruns a portion of the code, then they also know where the function is from.

Comment: Thanks @DanChaltiel , duplicitousness was mostly for the benefit of human-readability. Including the ```library()``` calls up top lets the reader know which are being called below at-a-glance, and including the package as prefix makes it completely unambiguous which function I am calling. E.g., when I call ```filter()```, it is dubiously obvious that I am calling the ```dplyr``` version and not the ```stats``` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to combine the names with newlines in each group as part of `summarise()`, using `paste(make, collapse = '\n')`.

```
tibble::as_tibble(mtcars, rownames = "make") %>%
  dplyr::filter(cyl == 4) %>% dplyr::group_by(vs, am) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(dark = n(), names = paste(make, collapse = "\n")) %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = vs, y = am, alpha = dark, label = names)) +
  ggplot2::geom_raster() +
  ggplot2::geom_text()
```

[image]